# ¿Cómo formatear fecha en Java?

Tags: java, date

Actualmente tengo una API que me devuelve una fecha en este formato:

```
1607474368095
```

Pero necesito que esté en formato `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

He probado a hacer un parseo con un `LocalDateTime` pero me da fallo.

Intento hacer un `getDate()` pero me dice que está deprecated.

Ahora mismo, no conozco ninguna forma de parsear una fecha dada en este formato.

Comment: Ese valor es un timestamp (un unix timestamp). Revisa de nuevo con esta info adicional...

Comment: @Alfabravo Unix timestamp se expresa en segundos. Éste valor incluye milisegundos.

Comment: Que versión de Java usas Victor?

Comment: Uso la versión de Java 1.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por acá dejo una manera más sencilla de hacerlo, queda al gusto del programador.

```
//inicializas un objeto Date con el valor que devuelve la API
Date date = new Date(1607474368095l);
//Generas el formato que deseas
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

//el método parse devuelve un objeto Date 
//y en su parámetro recibe una fecha pero en formato String        
date = format.parse(format.format(date));

//hacemos la prueba
System.out.println("" + date);
```

> Tue Dec 08 18:39:28 CST 2020

Acá puedes ver que date se hace el formateo:

*date = format.parse(**format.format(date)**);*

```
System.err.println("" + format.format(date));
```

> 08-12-2020 18:39:28

Comment: Pero estás usando Date (que se considera obsoleta) y SimpleDateFormat (que no es *thread-safe* y también está obsoleta). Desde Java 8 (2011) se aconseja usar el paquete `java.time` para manejar fechas y momentos.

Comment: @PabloLozano como lo puse al inicio queda al gusto del programador, a demás en algunos lugares de trabajo (asumiendo un ambiente laboral) aún utilizan versiones anteriores de JAVA

Comment: Por favor, no enseñe a los jóvenes a usar la `SimpleDateFormat` clase obsoleta y notoriamente problemática . Al menos no como gusto para el programador. Y no sin reserva alguna. Tenemos mucho mejor en [`java.time`, la API moderna de fecha y hora de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), y su `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: Tengo en cuenta todo lo que comentáis. Efectivamente uso la versión Java 1.8, pero si en algún momento uso una versión superior, entonces seguiré las otras recomendaciones.

Comment: La versión 8 **YA** incluye estas clases. No son ninguna novedad

Answer (score 10):

Ese formato es el llamado Unix Time, milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970. Puedes convertirlo a `LocalDateTime` así:

```java
long timestamp = 1607474368095L;
Instant tempInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(test_timestamp)
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(tempInstant, 
        TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());
```

Y entonces sólo necesitas usar un `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String text = ldt.format(formatter);
```

Comment: Efectivamente, esta respuesta es válida, hace el formateo tal y como necesito y te agradezco el aporte.

Answer (score 5):

Esta es una forma de realizarlo usando Calendar setTimeInMillis():

```
    Long dateMillis = 1607474368095L;

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateMillis);
    String fechaFinal = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    
    System.out.println(fechaFinal);
```

Salida:

```
08-12-2020 18:39:28
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplemente use la clase [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) en su implementación [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
public final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.format(date);
```